# Is it possible to use ffmpeg to move part of the video to another position and crop the video at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

I have a video file let's say it's the following one.

[image]

What I want is the following operations:

- Copy the part in the red rectangle to the bottom-right corner for the whole video.
- Remove the left red shadowed part of the whole video.

So the expected result looks like this:

[image]

Notice the part has been copied to the bottom-right corner and the left part has been removed.

Is is possible to do this with ffmpeg or I must use something like Adobe Premiere Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "split=2[pip][full];[pip]crop=W:H:X:Y[pip];[full][pip]overlay=W-w:H-h,crop=iw-M:ih:M:0" -c:a copy out
```

where W,H,X,Y are as per your diagram. M is the margin from the left edge which needs to be cropped out. Select M so that `iw-M` results in an even number.